# How to open url in default browser using titanium in Blackberry

Tags: titanium, blackberry-10

I am currently working on a project in titanium .I wish to open url in default browser of BB10
simulator instead of webview used in the app on click event .I am using the following code

```
var win =Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'Test'
});
var webview=Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url:"http://demo.php.otssolutions.com/videoapp-uat/home"
});
win.add(webview);

webview.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var url=e.url;
    Ti.API.info(url);

        Titanium.Platform.openURL("http://demo.php.otssolutions.com/videoapp-uat/home");

});
win.open();
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Normally that should work. Did the console shows the URL, so the click event fires?

Comment: Hey Derdida, thanks for your comment and time!!!, The above code works well and good for iPhone and Android platform ,But cat get it working for blackberry.The console prints "[INFO] undefined" as a result of "info " command,but the call definately comes in the block of event listener.